# How to register listening for Contact changes on android 2.0?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, android-2.0-eclair

How to register a content observer to listen for changes in the contact database in android 2.0? What URI should I use?

Thank you

Comment: I tried RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, but in my ContentObserver the onChange method is called for all contacts every time a contact is changed

Comment: Is that not what you want — or do you mean that you receive an `onChange` call for *every* contact when you change *any* contact? :)
I believe `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` is meant to be *the* URI like `People.CONTENT_URI` was previously?

Comment: Yes, I receive an onChange call for every contact when I change any contact. I will try ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

Answer (score 0):

ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

For Example:

```
mContactsObserver = new ContactsObserver(mHandler);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, mContactsObserver);
```

Source:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

Comment: I believe you mean "ContentObserver" not "ContactsObserver" -- the latter does not exist as far as I can tell.

Comment: Resurrecting an old Q, but I believe `ContactsObserver` is just referring to a custom implementation of `ContentObserver`, as `ContentObserver` doesn't actually do anything by default.